# Tailwind Styling is not applying on first item on list item

Tags: html, css, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm currently learning Tailwind CSS. I'm using Tailwind CSS to style a list of items within a flex container. I have applied tailwind class : **space-y-6** and **space-x-6** on my list item. The styling is applied on all the list items but not on first one. Space is not applied for first item in the list.

Here is the code:
(It does not have any other content and no external styling is used)

```
     <ul class="flex space-y-6 space-x-6">
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/image.jpg" alt="Profile Photo"></a>
            <a href="#">Cersei</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/image.jpg" alt="Profile Photo"></a>
            <a href="#">Arya Stark</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/image.jpg" alt="Profile Photo"></a>
            <a href="#">Danerays</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="assets/image.jpg" alt="Profile Photo"></a>
            <a href="#">Sansa Stark</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

How to make that styling applies on the first item of the list item?

Answer (score 0):

Space Between utility is used for controlling the space between child elements. But this utility has a limitation that it can be used for adding margin to all-but-the-first-item in a group.

A workaround for this is to use padding utility specifically on first child.

```
 <ul class="flex space-y-6 space-x-6">
    <li class="pt-6 pl-6"> <!-- added padding utility -->
        <a href="#"><img src="assets/image.jpg" alt="Profile Photo"></a>
        <a href="#">Cersei</a>
    </li>
   <!-- .... -->
</ul>
```